# bulk indexing in elasticsearch issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce

**I am trying to index a file by using below code:
But I am wondering why it is not happening:
Could any body explain the reason for not indexing.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String line;
    List l=new ArrayList();
    FileReader file=new FileReader("test.txt");     
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(file);
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        l.add(line);
    }
    br.close();
    System.out.println(l);
    Client client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("10.210.51.207",9300));    
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk(); 


    // either use client#prepare, or use Requests# to directly build index/delete requests      
    Iterator it=l.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        String name=(String) it.next();
        bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("cricket", "cric", "1")
                   .setSource(jsonBuilder()                     
                   .startObject() 
                   .field("user", name)
                   .field("postDate", new Date()) 
                   .field("message", "BULK INSERT TEST")
                   .endObject()  
                   )  ); 

    }




    GetResponse getResponse = client.prepareGet("cricket", "cric", "1").execute().actionGet();      
    System.out.println(getResponse.getSourceAsString());
    System.out.println("Bulk request finished");

}
```

Thans in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your `bulkRequest` to add the document(s) to the index.

Please add the following before your `GetResponse`.

```
 BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

You can then check the properties on the `bulkResponse` object to ensure it completed successfully.